# Regex Directory matching in Groovy

Tags: gradle, groovy

As part of Gradle delete task, I would like to delete all tar files beginning with `CSW` and ending with `.tar.gz` from a directory.  How can I achieve it with Groovy?

I tried something like below:

```
delete (file('delivery/').eachDirMatch(~/^CSW$.*.gz/))
```

But it doesn't work. How do I employ the regex in Groovy. As compared to shell it is something like `rm -rf CSW*.tar.gz`

Comment: Do you want directory matching? That sounds like file matching

Comment: The directory that I want matched is actually inside the directory called `delivery`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer with a gradle solution as you refer to gradle in your question. Something along the lines of:

```
myTask(type: Delete)  {
  delete fileTree(dir: 'delivery' , include: '**/CSW*.tar.gz')
}
```

where the `delete` method call is configuration time and configures what *will be deleted* when the task eventually runs. For details it might be worth looking through the [gradle docs on the fileTree method](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:fileTree(java.util.Map)).

If you need to stay pure groovy you could do something along the lines of:

```
new AntBuilder().fileScanner {
  fileset(dir: 'delivery', includes: '**/CSW*.tar.gz')
}.each { File f -> 
  f.delete()
}
```

If this code lives in a gradle script I would recommend sticking with option one as it retains the gradle up-to-date checking and fits well within the gradle [configuration vs execution time pattern](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html).

If you really want to go regex as opposed to the above style patterns you can certainly do that, though I would personally not see much of a point given your requirements.